# Is there a PHP configuration that will automatically escape double quotes?

Tags: php

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a PHP setting that will automatically escape double quotes.

My issue is that on my local server, i'm posting this string to the server:

```
{"0":{"id":"19","goal":"34"},"1":{"id":"22","goal":"657675"},"2":{"id":"21","goal":"456"}}
```

and it works fine. However, on the production server, I post the same string, and when I echo it out it is changed to:

```
{\"0\":{\"id\":\"19\",\"goal\":\"34\"},\"1\":{\"id\":\"22\",\"goal\":\"657675\"},\"2\":{\"id\":\"21\",\"goal\":\"456\"}}
```

I managed to fix it with a string_replace() call, but I would like to know why this is happening. The production server and local server are using the same code and were updated to use the same data, so I'm assuming the discrepency must be caused by server settings, but I have never heard of a setting that does that.

Has anyone experienced something like this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. It's called Magic Quotes:

http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc

You generally want to turn this off, and manually handle escaping as necessary.

Comment: +1 (beat me to it).  I'd also recommend reading through [this document section](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)...

Comment: @ircmaxell Thanks, I've added that link to my answer :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Now that you guys mention it I've heard a lot about magic quotes, but I guess I didn't understand exactly what they do. We use other methods of protecting against SQL injection so that shouldn't be an issue. I really hate when I fix something without understanding the problem, so thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This is typically an issues with "Magic Quotes". They are evil, IMO. You [should disable them](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) if possible.

They are meant to protect you from SQL injection attacks, so be careful after you disable them.

Comment: They aren't very effective at protecting from SQL Injection attacks though, so if you were depending on them you need to do an audit of your code anyway. :)

Comment: Fact. I've used mysql_real_escape_string in the past, but have since moved onto PDO / Active Record. PDO is pretty nice once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score -3):

You could try to use single quotes in the posted data rather than double

Comment: Single quotes will be escaped too. He needs to turn magic_quotes_* off.